# Transforming admin units into hexagons: the assignment problem

Tags: r, administrative-boundaries, hexagonal-grid, hexagon-binning

I have an administrative tessellation with about 8000 units (the [Census tracts of California](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_tracts.html)) and, for the sake of visualisation, I would like to transform it into regular hexagons (or squares). I found the nice [R package geogrid](https://github.com/jbaileyh/geogrid) that works well on small cases (e.g. up to 300 units). To match the geometries is a O^3 or O^4 problem: [The Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm) would take way too long on even moderately large input (several hours or even days for 5000 objects).

Is there any other package (in R or on other platforms) to do this at a larger scale? Is there a **sub-optimal alternative to the Hungarian algorithm** that would solve this assignment problem?

This is an example from geogrid that shows exactly what I want to do:

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the existing grids with geofacet? Uses R as well, they have European grids you can download.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hafen/grid-designer/master/grid_list.json

Comment: Can you share your data? I can imagine convergence is hard for many patterns. Is there anything odd in yours, like holes, islands, or nested polygons?

Comment: I added the data

Comment: Don't know in what sense this solve_LSAP solution is optimal, as I obtained an hexmap of entities far more displaced than that resulting from calculate_grid method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it by using another implementation of the Hungarian algorithm that completes even on larger datasets. Here's the full function:

```
generateHexBins <- function( sdf, grid_type='hexagonal', seed = 1 ){
  require(geogrid)
  require(rgeos)
  require(clue)
  require(sp)

  new_cells <- geogrid::calculate_grid(shape = sdf, grid_type = grid_type, seed = seed)
  # THIS DOESN'T COMPLETE, using clue::solve_LSAP instead
  # resulthex <- geogrid::assign_polygons(sdf, new_cells) 

  old_points = rgeos::gCentroid(sdf, byid = T)
  new_points = new_cells[[1]]
  cells = new_cells[[2]]
  # get polygon IDs
  pid <- sapply(slot(cells, "polygons"), function(x) slot(x, "ID"))
  # calculate distance matrix
  distmatrix <- sp::spDists(new_points, old_points, longlat = FALSE)
  # apply hungarian algorithm
  sol <- clue::solve_LSAP(distmatrix)
  grid_sdf = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(cells, data.frame( 
                 row.names = pid, ORIG_ID = sol[seq_along(sol)] ))
  stopifnot(nrow(grid_sdf)==nrow(sdf))
  grid_sdf
}
```